# How to get true content height of DOM element that is being cropped by overflow: hidden (for smooth css transition to height: auto)?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

## Solution:

Thanks to @Kalimah, this works in `composition api & script setup`:

```
<script setup>
const state = reactive({
    meetCardHeight: 100
})

const element = ref(null)

const changeElementHeight = () => {
    if (state.meetCardHeight !== element.value.scrollHeight) {
        state.meetCardHeight = element.value.scrollHeight
    } else {
        state.meetCardHeight = 100
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="element" class="w-6/12 p-4 mx-auto rounded border border-slate-400 bg-slate-50 shadow cursor-pointer hover:border-slate-600 hover:shadow-md transition mb-4 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500" :style="{ height: state.meetCardHeight + 'px'}" @click="changeElementHeight">

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto at atque beatae commodi cumque delectus dolor doloremque enim est et eum ex facere id illum incidunt, ipsum iusto labore laboriosam libero magnam minima molestias nobis nulla officia perspiciatis placeat porro possimus quo sequi tempore tenetur velit voluptatibus? Adipisci amet asperiores, autem explicabo fuga fugiat, id illum nobis obcaecati quam quasi, quibusdam tempora voluptatem? Adipisci aliquam at dignissimos dolore doloribus eaque itaque minus nam possimus quae quia temporibus vel, vero!</p>

  </div>
</template>
```

It will expand the `div` to its `height-auto` size with a smooth transition.

## Original Question:

I'm trying to compute the true `height` of all text in this `component`, despite part of it being hidden by `overflow: hidden` (tailwind):

```
<script setup>

const state = reactive({
    meetCardHeight: 100
})

</script>

<template>
  <div ref="element" class="w-6/12 p-4 mx-auto rounded border border-slate-400 bg-slate-50 shadow cursor-pointer hover:border-slate-600 hover:shadow-md transition mb-4 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500" :style="{ height: state.meetCardHeight + 'px'}">

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto at atque beatae commodi cumque delectus dolor doloremque enim est et eum ex facere id illum incidunt, ipsum iusto labore laboriosam libero magnam minima molestias nobis nulla officia perspiciatis placeat porro possimus quo sequi tempore tenetur velit voluptatibus? Adipisci amet asperiores, autem explicabo fuga fugiat, id illum nobis obcaecati quam quasi, quibusdam tempora voluptatem? Adipisci aliquam at dignissimos dolore doloribus eaque itaque minus nam possimus quae quia temporibus vel, vero!</p>

  </div>
</template>
```

The current component height is set to `100px` for the `overflow` property to take effect. Is there a way to determine the `height` that `h1` and `p` tags would result in, if `overflow` would not be present?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the height with [scrollHieght](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) property. It is a native JS property and is independet of vue or any other libraries.

Example:

```js
console.log("Full Height", document.querySelector(".container").scrollHeight + "px");
```

```css
.container{
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto at atque beatae commodi cumque delectus dolor doloremque enim est et eum ex facere id illum incidunt, ipsum iusto labore laboriosam libero magnam minima molestias nobis nulla officia perspiciatis placeat porro possimus quo sequi tempore tenetur velit voluptatibus? Adipisci amet asperiores, autem explicabo fuga fugiat, id illum nobis obcaecati quam quasi, quibusdam tempora voluptatem? Adipisci aliquam at dignissimos dolore doloribus eaque itaque minus nam possimus quae quia temporibus vel, vero!
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto at atque beatae commodi cumque delectus dolor doloremque enim est et eum ex facere id illum incidunt, ipsum iusto labore laboriosam libero magnam minima molestias nobis nulla officia perspiciatis placeat porro possimus quo sequi tempore tenetur velit voluptatibus? Adipisci amet asperiores, autem explicabo fuga fugiat, id illum nobis obcaecati quam quasi, quibusdam tempora voluptatem? Adipisci aliquam at dignissimos dolore doloribus eaque itaque minus nam possimus quae quia temporibus vel, vero!
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci architecto at atque beatae commodi cumque delectus dolor doloremque enim est et eum ex facere id illum incidunt, ipsum iusto labore laboriosam libero magnam minima molestias nobis nulla officia perspiciatis placeat porro possimus quo sequi tempore tenetur velit voluptatibus? Adipisci amet asperiores, autem explicabo fuga fugiat, id illum nobis obcaecati quam quasi, quibusdam tempora voluptatem? Adipisci aliquam at dignissimos dolore doloribus eaque itaque minus nam possimus quae quia temporibus vel, vero!</p>

  </div>
```